# How to setup AdMob mediation with correct values

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I am new to AdMob and currently showing ads using the AdMob publisher ID. What I don't get is to set the correct values for these mediation things. I have the following screenshot and want to know what A, B and C means and how do we get paid if these values affect our payments. What those dollar values actually do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot didn't come through.

The order of the mediation list from highest to lowest is used to determine in which order to query an ad network for an ad.

Admob suggests that you set your mediation values to roughly what you get from each of the ad networks. This will let you easily track and update which ad networks are providing best value and hence who you should offer space up to first.

Comment: If that so we can put a bigger number in those values right? Like $1000, $10000? What is the 'Best Value' you have mentioned?

Comment: You can put whatever value you like. A higher value would cause a network to appear at that value in the mediation chain. It just determines ordering. But eCPM values are typically $0.20 to $2.00 depending upon ad type.